# Splitting text in python but treating commas, periods etc as separate 'words'

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to break down sentences into words. Normally I'd use `textstring.split(' ')`, but I'm also looking to split comma's and periods, separately, so "No, thank you" would be split into `["No", ",", "thank", "you"]` rather than `["No,", "thank", "you"]`.

I thought of doing it this way:

```
textstring.replace(",", " ,").replace(".", " .").split(' ')
```

But that feels a bit hacky. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked into [`nltk`](http://www.nltk.org/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can split them apart with a Regular Expression like this

```
textstring = "No, thank you"
import re
print re.findall(r'\w+|\S+', textstring)
# ['No', ',', 'thank', 'you']
```

`\w+` will get all the consecutive alpha-numeric characters and `_`, `\S` will get all the consecutive non-space characters. The `|` means match either the `\w+` or `\S+` part.